# Strange OSGI error while reading an excel file

Tags: java, spring, osgi, apache-poi

I am having an error in my very simple Spring project. The goal of this project is very simple: It's a restful service and it connects to an excel file with Apache POI and read some value in cell and returns it, so i can see it in web browser when I go to localhost
Output is something like this: Hello world, Excel value is: 5

I debugged the code many times and I am sure that this error comes from the "Worksheet" line

```
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("file.xlsx"));
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    Row row = sheet.getRow(1);
    Cell cell = row.getCell(0);

    value = Integer.toString((int) cell.getNumericCellValue());
```

Here is the error message:

```
initialized with Attributes:{applicationName=BasicService, bundleName=Basic-Serv
ice}
ERROR: Bundle dsp.core [237] EventDispatcher: Error during dispatch. (java.lang.
NullPointerException)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ge.dsp.core.spi.impl.ServiceManagerServiceImpl.addRegisteredServi
ce(ServiceManagerServiceImpl.java:876)
        at com.ge.dsp.core.spi.impl.ServiceManagerServiceImpl.addRegisteredServi
ce(ServiceManagerServiceImpl.java:856)
        at com.ge.dsp.core.bootloader.impl.CoreServiceListener.serviceChanged(Co
reServiceListener.java:79)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher$4.run(EventDispatcher
.java:925)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeServiceListener
Callback(EventDispatcher.java:921)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(
EventDispatcher.java:793)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireServiceEvent(Even
tDispatcher.java:543)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireServiceEvent(Felix.java:4260)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.registerService(Felix.java:3275)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleCo
ntextImpl.java:346)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl$3.run(Blu
eprintContainerImpl.java:443)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl$3.run(Blu
eprintContainerImpl.java:441)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.registerS
ervice(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:441)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ServiceRecipe.register(ServiceRe
cipe.java:190)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.registerS
ervices(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:690)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(Blu
eprintContainerImpl.java:369)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(Bluep
rintContainerImpl.java:261)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:47
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.ExecutorServiceWrapper.run(Execu
torServiceWrapper.java:106)
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.impl.DiscardableRunnable.r
un(DiscardableRunnable.java:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:47
1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.
run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: It would be nice to know what is on line ServiceManagerServiceImpl.java:876

Comment: @BalazsZsoldos It returns something like this:int result = version.getMajor() - other.getMajor();
    if (result != 0)
    {
      return result;
    }

Comment: Next question is: Where do the following variables come from: version, other, result? You know it is pretty hard to find out the cause of a NPE without the source (and the source of the classes that are in the stacktrace)

Comment: Apache POI doesn't provide an OSGi bundle as standard. Where did you get yours from?

Comment: `NullPointerException` is not an OSGi error, it's an error that can occur in any Java code that contains bugs. There is no way to help you here if you don't post your code. I see that you work for GE, so perhaps it is not possible to publish the code. In that case you should seek help from your colleagues at GE.

Comment: @NeilBartlett, Yes I am afraid I can't post further. Thanks everyone for the help.